# CLI based Web API

Tags: php, api, command-line-interface

I'm writing a PHP app which should support both CLI and web API. Currently CLI stuff is ready so I thought that it would be nice to use the existing controllers and validators for web API as they do the same.

Eg, I could convert `http://api.domain.com/status-get`

into the command

```
php app status-get -f=json
```

and execute with `exec()`

Generally it works but I'm curious is that right solution? Am I missing some possible risks and caveats? So far I feel that this API won't be blazing fast because of exec()

Comment: I would avoid using `exec`(handling output from exec can be somewhat limiting), instead I would handle it with routing in a typical MVC type architecture.  Basically you route both calls to a uniform framework that sits as an application layer.

Comment: I use escapeshellarg() and escapeshellcmd() plus extra sanitization and validation against a list of allowed commands before it gets to exec(). I don't think PHP is a problem

Comment: At first I thought you had `eval` instead of `exec`, but there is still some limitations with using a command line call from a http call, such as the output.   Those are just my thoughts, it's your stuff do what you want, but you asked an Opinionated question, so I gave you my Opinionated answer.  Ideally you would want a application layer that doesn't care where the request came from, that's just a good practice to have.

Comment: Just for example, I use Code Igniter, and I have a ton of command line calls (for various reason) most of these are from cron or a queuing system, so I have a special controller that has it's own index outside of the webroot, but I can route command line calls to any CI controller, or via HTTP.  Makes life easy that way.  I do that one outside of the webroot for security reasons.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts